# Return only unique pairs of two indexes of lists within a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like [name1,name2,val1,val2]:

```
[['a','b',4,5],
['x','y',2,10],
['b','a',5,4],
['d','y',8,10],
['y','d',10,8],
['a','d',4,8]]
```

What I would like to do is filter this list of lists so that only unique combinations of name1 and name2 remain, regardless of their order:

```
[['a','b',4,5],
['x','y',2,10],
['d','y',8,10],
['a','d',4,8]]
```

using the comments, the best I could come up with is:
the best I can come up with is

```
def removedupes(lst):
    newlist = []
    unique = set()
    for i in lst:
        if i[0] > i[1]:
            templist = [i[1],i[0],i[3],i[4],i[1]+i[0]]
        else:
            templist = [i[0],i[1],i[3],i[4],i[0]+i[1]]
        if templist[-1] not in unique:
            newlist.append(templist[:-1])
       unique.add(i[-1])                                    
   return newlist
```

just wondering if there's a more pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: how do you decide which unique pair to keep? what have you tried?

Comment: I'd keep track of `(name1, name2)` and `(name2, name1)` pairs in a `set`. Only keep sublists where you haven't seen the combination yet.

Comment: @Sayse it can be any of the unique pairs, all the associated data is contained in each row so the particular row that is within the dataset is irrelevant.

Comment: I suggest you canonicalize it so that `name1` and `name2` are in alphabetical order. Then you can easily compare for duplicates.

Comment: Please add your code and [edit]s to the post -- not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the data you can reformat your input to be more amenable to manipulation.

```py
>>> {tuple(sorted(((x[0], x[2]), (x[1], x[3])))) for x in data}
{(('a', 4), ('b', 5)),
 (('a', 4), ('d', 8)),
 (('d', 8), ('y', 10)),
 (('x', 2), ('y', 10))}
```

Brief breakdown:

1. Convert each row into the format `((name1, val1), (name2, val2))`
2. Sort each row to allow comparison
3. Use a `set` to filter out duplicates

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood question and I don't think this does exactly what OP is looking for.

---

Here's how I would do it:

```
data = [['a','b',4,5],
['x','y',2,10],
['b','a',5,4],
['d','y',8,10],
['y','d',10,8],
['a','d',4,8]]

def foo(data):
    uniques = {}
    for n1, n2, v1, v2 in data:
        if n2 < n1:
            n1, n2 = n2, n1
        uniques[(n1, n2)] = (v1, v2)
    return [(n1, n2, v1, v2) for (n1, n2), (v1, v2) in uniques.items()]

print(foo(data))
```

Prints:

```
[('a', 'b', 5, 4), ('x', 'y', 2, 10), ('d', 'y', 10, 8), ('a', 'd', 4, 8)]
```

When there's a collision (i.e. two elements with the same `(n1, n2)`, the code chooses the newer one.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dict to keep track of the sorted pairs, which needs to convert to tuple to get an inmutable.

```
data = [
        ['a','b',4,5],
        ['x','y',2,10],
        ['b','a',5,4],
        ['d','y',8,10],
        ['y','d',10,8],
        ['a','d',4,8]
       ]

def foo(llist):
    dic = {tuple((k1, k2) if k2 > k1 else (k2,k1)):v for k1, k2, *v in llist}
    return [list(k)+list(v) for k,v in dic.items()]


>>>foo(data)

[['b', 'a', 5, 4], ['x', 'y', 2, 10], ['y', 'd', 10, 8], ['a', 'd', 4, 8]]
```

Notes: This answer:

- breaks if the two pair elements cannot be compared ;
- keeps the last sublist in case of collision, this is correct as the specifications do not provide a rule for such a case ;
- accepts any number of 'values' (i.e. elements that are not in the two first places of the sub lists), even more that the length of sublists varies.

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's write a list comprehension (that can readily be a generator expression) for the name components of each sublist, with them sorted.

```
[(a, b) if a < b else (b, a) for a, b, *_ in data]
```

Now, we can get a `set` of them to have the uniques.

```
>>> set((a, b) if a < b else (b, a) for a, b, *_ in data)
{('x', 'y'), ('a', 'd'), ('d', 'y'), ('a', 'b')}
```

Now we just need to be able to look up entries from `data` based on those tuples.

If we were looking for the combo `('a', 'd')` (or `('d', 'a')`):

```
>>> next(filter((lambda x: ('a', 'd') == (x[0], x[1]) if x[0] < x[1] else ('a', 'd') == (x[1], x[0])), data), None)
['a', 'd', 4, 8]
```

Now we just have to expand that to work on everything in our set.

```
>>> names_set = set((a, b) if a < b else (b, a) for a, b, *_ in data)
>>> [next(filter((lambda x: names == (x[0], x[1]) if x[0] < x[1] else names == (x[1], x[0])), data), None) for names in names_set]
[['x', 'y', 2, 10], ['a', 'd', 4, 8], ['d', 'y', 8, 10], ['a', 'b', 4, 5]]
```

We can also write this so that the conditional expression simply returns the correct tuple to compare to.

```
>>> [next(filter((lambda x: names == ((x[0], x[1]) if x[0] < x[1] else (x[1], x[0]))), data), None) for names in s]
[['x', 'y', 2, 10], ['a', 'd', 4, 8], ['d', 'y', 8, 10], ['a', 'b', 4, 5]]
```

Either way, the final result:

```
[['x', 'y', 2, 10], 
 ['a', 'd', 4,  8], 
 ['d', 'y', 8, 10], 
 ['a', 'b', 4,  5]]
```